# Does react-native creates the corresponding android activities in android after compilation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component, react-native-bridge

I was going through the react-native philosophy and I came to know that when you compile the react-native app, it compiles the JS code into corresponding native app. Like in case of android it will generate the java code.
My question is, does it means after the compilation, each JS screen will be one android activity..??
Because in my case, I need the control of each JS screen on the android native side.

Something like this

```
react-native Screen A   -> Android Activity A
react-native Screen B   -> Android Activity B
```

I am not sure, If this is realistic approach. But I want suggestions, If this is the real compilation case or not.

P.s : I am android developer and quite new to react-native.

Comment: as far as i know, react-native and flutter and other like those frameworks only have one activity and everything happnes there, so it may seem there are many activistes, actually only one activity exists

Comment: @AhmedKhattab I was thinking the same, Like on the native side they may be having one container (Activity) and they keep updating the views and transitions in the same container.

Comment: extactly you are right